# Was that Geralt's mother or just a dream?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-witcher

I am talking about [The Witcher](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5180504/). Spoilers Ahead.

When Geralt fell sick in S01E08 a man carried him in search of aid. While they rested in a jungle, Geralt saw his mother. He was angry at her, "Visenna", for abandoning him as a child. There was a conversation about his mother's reasons. During this she attempted to heal Geralt. Then, he awakes and it appears as if this had been a dream.

Was this magic? Did his mother actually heal him? Or was it just a fever dream?

Comment: It is complicated... because it was a dream and at the same time a mysterious sorceress likely to be her (Visenna= his mother) is the who healed his wound (a bite).

Comment: It was just a forest, not a jungle ☺️ As explained in the accepted answer it's ambigous. However there's one fact that might be a small suggestion it's happening for real. Visenna mentions that other wizards are fighting Nilfgaard in Sodden and it's very unlikely that Geralt knew about that.

Comment: related https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178021/how-many-of-geralts-visions-in-something-more-reflect-real-events

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This scene is left intentionally ambiguous (as in the book):

> One my favourite moments in Sword of Destiny is Geralt dreaming about meeting his mother.
>
> Is it a fever dream? We're actually not even sure when we read it. And that's something I really wanted to capture the essence of in the final episode, which is finally getting to understand where Geralt came from... The fun part of doing [the scene] as a fever dream, is we're not sure what he's creating, what he's remembering, and what's real and what's not. And it's actually something we're going to continue playing with for the run of this series.
>
> - Lauren Schmidt Hissrich, [interview with ign.com](https://uk.ign.com/articles/2019/12/21/the-witcher-season-1-ending-explained-geralt-mother-visenna-sodden-yennefer-ciri)